# Cumulative Sum with Eigen

Tags: c++, c++14, eigen, eigen3

My objective is to have partial_sum() to work with Eigen Arrays.
Looks like Eigen arrays do not have members named .begin() and .end().
The code below does NOT compile. Any ideas to fix it without explicitely implementing partial_sum() (which I already did) and without using std::vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <numeric>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  int N = 5;
  ArrayXf A(N,1);
  ArrayXf C(N,1);

  A(0) = 1.0;
  A(1) = 2.0;
  A(2) = 3.0;
  A(3) = 4.0;
  A(4) = 5.0;

  partial_sum(A.begin(), A.end(), C.begin(), plus<float>());

  printf("Output vector C \n");
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    cout << C(i) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the second `for` in your implementation?

Comment: Your commented out line works as expected (after adding `std::` and not trying to assign the returned iterator to the container): https://godbolt.org/z/hCU9ai -- You need the master branch of Eigen, though. If you still have problems, provide a [mre]!

Comment: Using `Eigen::Map` should not make a difference, but **you can't assign an iterator to `mC`**: https://godbolt.org/z/sbX3JD

Comment: If you declare A and C as vector<float> the code above works perfectly (provided you change round brackets with square brackets). Question is, can I have partial_sum to work with Eigen arrays?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html

`std::begin` only works for Eigen 3.4 and onward. Your code worked for me without any issues using Eigen 3.4.